# Probability problem: n different balls in n different boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Problem**

Suppose $n$ different balls are distributed in $n$ different boxes. Calculate the probability that each box is not empty when distributed the balls.

I'll define the sample space as $\Omega=\{(x_1,...,x_n) : x_i= \text{the box that corresponds to the i-th ball}, x_i \in \{1,...,n\}\}$, and the event $A=\{(x_1,...,x_n) : x_i= \text{the box that corresponds to the i-th ball}, x_i \in \{1,...,n\}\, x_i \neq x_j \text {if} i \neq j\}$.

I want to calculate $P(A)$, but I know that $P(A)=1-P(A^c)$.

$A^c$ is the set of outcomes where one or more of the boxes is empty.

I think I can describe $A^c=\cup_{i=1}^n C_i$, where $C_i=\{\text{the i-th box is empty}\}$. It is clear that this is not a disjoint union so  I cannot affirm $P(A^c)=\cup P(C_i)$, maybe I must use the inclusion-exclusion formula.

I don't know if this is a correct way to approach a solution, I would appreciate if someone could write how I apply the exclusion-inclusion formula and correct any mistakes I could have done. Also if somebody has another solution or wants to complete my solution, he or she is very welcomed to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a first ball. It will end up in an empty box. Then place a second ball. The probability that it is placed in an empty box is $\frac{n-1}{n}$. Now place a third ball. The probability that it is placed in an empty box is $\frac{n-2}{n}$. Going on like this you come to a probability that each ball is placed in an empty box (and consequently each box is not empty after placing the balls) of: $$\frac{n}{n}\times\frac{n-1}{n}\times\frac{n-2}{n}\times\cdots\times\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n!}{n^n}$$

Answer (score 2):

Each of $n$ balls can land in each of $n$ boxes, so there are $D=n^n$ distributions possible. For each box to be non-empty you need a distribution in which each ball sits in its own box, which is equivalent to assigning each of $n$ ball numbers to one of $n$ box numbers - and each such assignment is just a permutation of $n$ natural numbers. There are $P_n = n!$ such permutations, so (assuming each distribution equally probable) the probability you seek is $$\frac {P_n} D = \frac{n!}{n^n}$$